Issue with Patrol Flutter tests
I have a question regarding running tests in Flutter using Patrol framework. Sometimes when I run the test it passes and sometimes it just fails with this message in report.

══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY FLUTTER TEST FRAMEWORK ╞═════════════════ The
following message was thrown: Multiple exceptions (3) were detected
during the running of the current test, and at least one was
unexpected.
═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
at
pl.leancode.patrol.PatrolJUnitRunner.runDartTest(PatrolJUnitRunner.java:135)
at
care.incision.teams.MainActivityTest.runDartTest(MainActivityTest.java:31)
Flutter 3.19.6 • channel stable Patrol CLI version: 2.7.0 patrol:
^3.6.1

I tried running the test each time, and sometimes it passed but sometimes it failed. I expect that it passes each time

that means theres an exception thrown that you did not catch in your test

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
